# NestJS how to validate body before image is uploaded?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, nestjs

I have a controller method that receives a file and a DTO.
I would like to validate my DTO before the file is uploaded.

What I tried is : create a validation interceptor where I can validate the request body, like this :

```
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, Logger, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ValidationInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  private logger = new Logger('ValidatioInterceptor');

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>();
    this.logger.verbose(`body: ${JSON.stringify(request.body)}`);
    // TODO validate body
    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

Then use it in my controller before the FileInterceptor, like this :

```
    @Put('/:id')
    @Roles(Role.ADMIN)
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard(), RolesGuard)
    @UseInterceptors(ValidationInterceptor, FileInterceptor('image'))
    updateUserById(
      @Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number,
      @Body(ValidationPipe) updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto,
      @UploadedFile() file: any,
    ): Promise<UserModel> {
    ...
   }
```

My problem is that the body is always empty in ValidationInterceptor.

This is somehow related to this question also, but no concrete answer provided :
[Nestjs: Image uploaded even if body validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477104/nestjs-image-uploaded-even-if-body-validation-fails/)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best way since your interceptor will not be usable for anything else. You should  validate your DTO in your controller function, before you save that file somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However, in my controller function, the file is already saved.. It is uploaded before, in the FileInterceptor. I also have multiple function like this, where I need to upload form data with file + data. So I plan to reuse the ValidationInterceptor if I can make it work.

Comment: @manolo_el_muchacho Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Jayffe Unfortunately no. I ended up using 2 different controller methods : one to update data (with DTO validation), the other to upload the file. Hope it helps.